# Что не правильно? Какая ошибка присутствует?

Tags: python

```
what=input("Введите операцию(+,-):")

x=float(input("Введите Первое Число:"))
y=float(input("Введите Второе Число:"))

If what== "+":
    c=x+y
    print("Результат"+ str(c))
If what== "-":
    c=x-y
    print("Результат"+ str(c))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` должно быть с маленькой буквы, т.е.

```
what=input("Введите операцию(+,-):")

x=float(input("Введите Первое Число:"))
y=float(input("Введите Второе Число:"))

if what== "+":
    c=x+y
    print("Результат"+ str(c))
if what== "-":
    c=x-y
    print("Результат"+ str(c))
```

Comment: SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement Выдаёт такую ошибку в первой строке...

Comment: вы точно все правильно скоропировали? У меня всё работает

Comment: Работает спасибо)

Comment: Если все хорошо примите ответ